docker SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'172.18.0.3'
I am trying to dockerize laravel application but I am getting this error
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'172.18.0.3'
docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:

    # Database Server
    database:
        image: mysql:8.4.0
        ports:
            -   3306:3306
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE="${DB_DATABASE}"
            - MYSQL_USER="${DB_USERNAME}"
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

    # PHP Service
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
                - APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"
        environment:
            - APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"
            - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - database
            
    
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        environment:
          - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

volumes:
    db-data: ~

.env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_database
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password

I tried using
username: user
password: password
in phpmyadmin but it show access denied error

Did you try to connect to it on localhost:3306 or database:3306?

@Eduard I connected to database:3306

The user, password and database variables are only used if no database exists when the container starts.
You most likely have an existing database in your db-data volume. Try doing docker compose down -v to delete the volume. Then, when you start the container again, a fresh volume is created and the variables are used to create a new database with a user and password with the specified values.
From the docs

Do note that none of the variables below will have any effect if you
start the container with a data directory that already contains a
database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on
container startup.

